# Suppress "Save As" prompt

Tags: vba, excel, csv, prompt

I looked this topic up and found some help but the suggestions do not seem to be working.

- I am opening a CSV file into EXCEL  make some changes and then want to save the results back to the same file name and the CSV format.
- I want to do this without the prompt that I am getting to make sure I want to save the file.
- We are using a macro enabled excel file to import the data make changes and then save.
- This whole process with initiated by a batch file that will open the Excel application and the designated file at regular period of time so that is why we do not want the prompt to stop the process.

Here is the code I am using in VBA to do the work, as well as the other subs I found that were suppose to help me suppress the prompt.

This code is in the `TheWorkbook` of the file and not a module.

Am I missing something?

*code*

```
Sub fixfile()
    Const strFileName = "W:\Webshare\Documents Acquired in 2017\Jim Excel\snr-room-schedule.csv"
    Dim wbkS As Workbook
    Dim wshS As Worksheet
    Dim wshT As Worksheet
    Set wshT = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    Set wbkS = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFileName)
    Set wshS = wbkS.Worksheets(1)
    wshS.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wshT.Range("A1")
    wbkS.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'This is the area of work that we doing to the data
    'Through here

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'IT WORKS TO DISABLE ALERT PROMPT

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "W:\Webshare\Documents Acquired in 2017\Jim Excel\snr-room-schedule.csv", FileFormat _
        :=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'RESETS DISPLAY ALERTS
    Application.Quit
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    fixfile
End Sub

Sub CloseandSave()
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before .Save and `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` after.

Comment: VBA Pete-->   I actually do have those two statements in the code.  False statement is the 10th line of code and the True statement is the 12 line of code.  THey surround the SaveAs  statement.
 I tried surrounding the Save in both (one at a time) of the Subroutines CloseandSave and BeforeClose but this added the prompt back in about the file already exists.   I really do not want any prompt to occur AT ALL.    I know I am writing over the existing file so that is ok.   IS this a problem because I am trying to save as a CSV format.  It needs to be that format.  Thanks for more help.

Comment: Your closing sub is missing the promt (not sure if you use it). Also, change `FileFormat :=xlCSVMSDOS` to `FileFormat:=xlCSV`.

Comment: I changed the FileFormat but that did not help.     I also don't know if I need the two final subroutines CloseandSave() and Workbook_BeforeClose().    I don't actually call them in fixfile()    I was thinking they might be "automatically" used by EXCEL when the application is trying to close and save.   Do I need to literally add those to fixfile sub.     I also tried adding the two prompts into the CloseandSave  ALSO but that did not help either.

Comment: No, `CloseandSave()` and `Workbook_BeforeClose()` are not used in your macro so you can remove those. But I don't know why your your macro is still prompting, so I have added a bounty on your question. Hopefully someone will have the answer to this.

Comment: There are a few things that I dont quite get in the workflow. Let me start with this. You append a worksheet (the csv) to the macro-enabled workbook (the one that has the code), and then you want to save it as csv. But, csv files are simply text files, they cannot have many worksheets, one and only one. What's the purpose?

Comment: @user1968084 Don't forget to click the check-mark if one of the answers below helped resolving your issue.

Answer (score 12):

The problems in your code are due to the following.

When you call `SaveAs` on the macro-enabled workbook, you had already appended a worksheet to it:

> `Set wshT = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))`

and then you're trying to save it as csv, which is a text file with only one worksheet, so Excel complains that you will loose information.

Moreover, you're doing the update to the csv twice: once in the

> `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= ...`

Where, as a result, the **current workbook becomes the saved workbook**, and then again in the `Workbook_BeforeClose`. In the latter you dont disable the alerts, but anyway there's no need to save again.

I have come to the conclusion that what you want is to use the macro-enabled wb just as a utility for calculation, and you care only for updating the `CSV` workbook.

For simplicity, we will disable the alerts for the whole session, because the macro-enabled WB is used as a utility and we dont want the batch job to stop for any reason. However you can do it the traditional way, before and after saving, if you feel more comfortable with it.

```
' Code module ThisWorkbook
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    fixCSVFile

    ' Do the following only if you want the macro-enabled WB to keep
    ' a copy of the CSV worksheet. but my feeling is you dont want to
    ' ThisWorkbook.Save
    '''''''''''''''''''''

     Application.Quit
End Sub

Sub fixCSVFile()
    Const strFileName = "W:\Webshare\Documents Acquired in 2017\Jim Excel\snr-room-schedule.csv"
    Dim wbkS As Workbook, wshS As Worksheet, wshT As Worksheet

    Set wshT = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    Set wbkS = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFileName)
    Set wshS = wbkS.Worksheets(1)

    wshS.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wshT.Range("A1")
    wbkS.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'This is the area of work that we doing to the data
    ' For purpose of testing:
    wshT.Range("A1").Value = wshT.Range("A1").Value + 1

    ' Now we will export back the modified csv
    wshT.Move '<- Here we have a temporary workbook copy of the modified csv
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=strFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

One more thing, the macro-enabled WB is now such that it closes as soon as it opens so it will be difficult to edit or modify (although there are workarounds). Therefore you should save a back-up copy of it without the `Application.Quit`, as a testing/maintenance copy. Only the copy that you put in production for the sake of the batch job should have the `Application.Quit` statement.

Comment: Now that it appeared that you only wanted to change the date of the CSV file to the current date/time, there was no need or VBA to do this. You could, in your script, simply [touch](http://superuser.com/a/764721) the CSV file...

Answer (score 7):

Based on the comment in the answers that the reason for opening the file and immediately saving it with no other changes...

> So we needed to do what we were doing to get the file edit date to
>   change but not the actual file.

...this is a ***complete*** [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). If you need to change a file's modified time, just change the file's modified time instead of jumping through all of the opening and re-saving hoops:

```
Sub UpdateFileModifiedDate()
    Const filePath = "W:\Webshare\Documents Acquired in 2017\Jim Excel\snr-room-schedule.csv"

    Dim handle As Integer
    handle = FreeFile
    Open filePath For Binary As #handle
    'Read the first byte.
    Dim first As Byte
    Get #handle, 1, first
    'Write it back
    Put #handle, 1, first
    Close #handle
End Sub
```

This will be insanely faster than your current process, will only set the file modified date and time to the time that you run the `Sub`, and doesn't risk any of the other issues you can run into cycling a CSV file through Excel (date formats and locale issues, truncating decimals, conversions to exponential notation, etc., etc.).

Comment: It is XY, but we all thought there was calculation stuff in that worksheet. I even wonder why use VBA at all for this, the batch job could simply [touch](http://superuser.com/a/764721) the CSV file...

Answer (score 5):

since you're going to *consciously* overwrite an existing file you can just:

- first delete it with a `Kill` command
- then do the `SaveAs`

so change this code section:

```
'This is the area of work that we doing to the data
'Through here

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'IT WORKS TO DISABLE ALERT PROMPT

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "W:\Webshare\Documents Acquired in 2017\Jim Excel\snr-room-schedule.csv", FileFormat _
    :=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'RESETS DISPLAY ALERTS
Application.Quit
```

to this:

```
'This is the area of work that we doing to the data
'Through here

Kill strFileName '<-- delete the old file

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "W:\Webshare\Documents Acquired in 2017\Jim Excel\snr-room-schedule.csv", FileFormat _
    :=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
Application.Quit
```

---

furthermore your code can be refactored by properly handling the `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet` objects and reduce the variables and code amount, like follows:

```
Sub fixfile()
    Const strFileName = "W:\Webshare\Documents Acquired in 2017\Jim Excel\snr-room-schedule.csv"

    Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFileName).Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Range("A1") '<--| open 'strFileName', reference and copy its 1st worksheet 'UsedRange' and paste it to a newly added worksheet in the macro workbook. After this statement we're left with the opened workbook as `ActiveWorkbook`
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False '<--| close `ActiveWorkbook`, i.e. the just opened one. We're left with macro workbook as `ActiveWorkbook` and its newly created worksheet as `ActiveSheet`

    'This is the area of work that we doing to the data
    'Through here

    ActiveSheet.Move '<--| move `ActiveSheet` (i.e. the newly created sheet in macro workbook) to a "new" workbook having that sheet as its only one. We're left with this "new" workbook as `ActiveWorkbook`
    Kill strFileName '<--| delete the "old" 'strFileName'
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False '<--| save `ActiveWorkbook` (i.e the "new" one) as the new 'strFileName' file
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False '<--| close `ActiveWorkbook` (i.e the "new" one) without changes (we just "SavedA"s it)
    Application.Quit     
End Sub
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask how to write confusing code that only takes up 3 lines.  He and most other people looking are trying to understand the problem.  I don't see how refactoring, combining multiple steps and getting rid of all the variables helps.  I wouldn't trust ActiveSheet/ActiveworkBook with a 10 foot pole.

Comment: @Profex, you seem to miss the first part of my answer which addresses OP's issue explaning the necessary details. The ones _really_ willing to understand the problem should read it and comment it to add helpful knowledge to the matter. While the "refactoring" part is kept at the end so it's something _additional_ that may be found useful or may be not, but nothing to be blamed for, I presume. The _"combining multiple steps"_ and the _"getting rid of all the variable helps"_ issues can be thought as harmful or useful in relation to the reader's actual level of VBA knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are making changes to two files. In addition to the csv file that you are opening, you appear to be adding a sheet to the excel file that is running the VBA code with these lines:

```
Dim wshT As Worksheet
Set wshT = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
```

So my guess is that you are indeed suppressing the save prompt for the csv file but you are also getting a save prompt for the changes you made to the excel workbook when you attempt to close it.  So I think you need to suppress that prompt as well by also turning off DisplayAlerts in the CloseAndSave sub, or wherever the excel workbook is actually being closed.

Comment: Good guess, also I would like to point out that pointing from a certain file with ActiveWorkbook reference is possibly to cause problems if you don't handle the activation thoroughly. If you want to be extra sure you are pointing to the correct workbooks I suggest that you also think about binding Workbooks objects to Variables and use them as pointers to avoid any extra problems.

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't get why you are copying the CSV sheet into a new sheet in the macro enabled workbook.  **This is where your problem starts!**

   - You should just be dealing with the data in `wshS` and saving `wbkS` instead.
     *Done, no more problems.*
2. When you call

   > ```
   > ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
   >     "W:\Webshare\Documents Acquired in 2017\Jim Excel\snr-room-schedule.csv", 
   >     FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False`
   > ```

   you're **renaming the current macro enabled file** within excel to the CSV file **as far as Excel sees it**.
3. When `Application.Quit` is called, it is going to call

   > ```
   > Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   >     ThisWorkbook.Save
   > End Sub
   > ```

   ***Which is where the prompt that you are complaining about is happening.***

   - Even if you remove it, after `Workbook_BeforeClose` is called, *Excel* is still going to check all the open files' `.Saved` flag.
   - *Excel* will prompt you to save any files where `.Saved = False`

But if you set **`ThisWorkbook.Saved = True`** then *Excel* will close the file without asking to save.

**Solution:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```